# Why is navigation property collection always empty

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Why are the navigation properties Assemblies and Components always empty in the following programs?

```
// Item.cs
public class Item
{
    public int ItemID { get; set; }
    public string Desc { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<BOM> Assemblies { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<BOM> Components { get; set; }
}

// BOM.cs
public class BOM
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int AssemblyID { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int ComponentID { get; set; }

    public int Qty { get; set; }

    public virtual Item Assembly { get; set; }
    public virtual Item Component { get; set; }
}

// TestDbContext.cs
public class TestDbContext : DbContext
{
    public TestDbContext()
        : base("name=Model1")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<TestDbContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<TestDbContext>());
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<BOM> BOMs { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<BOM>()
            .HasRequired<Item>(b => b.Assembly) // BOM requires Assembly Item
            .WithMany(b => b.Assemblies)       // Item includes many Assemblies (BOMs)
            .HasForeignKey(b => b.AssemblyID)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<BOM>()
            .HasRequired<Item>(b => b.Component)    // BOM requires Component Item
            .WithMany(b => b.Components)           // Item include many Components (BOMs)
            .HasForeignKey(b => b.ComponentID)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);


        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}

// TestController.cs
public string CreateBOM()
{
    // Create the items
    Item bike = new Item();
    bike.Desc = "Bike";
    db.Items.Add(bike);

    Item frame = new Item();
    frame.Desc = "Frame";
    db.Items.Add(frame);

    Item wheel = new Item();
    wheel.Desc = "Wheel";
    db.Items.Add(wheel);

    // Create the Bill Of Materials
    BOM line1 = new BOM();
    line1.Assembly = bike;
    line1.Component = frame;
    line1.Qty = 1;
    db.BOMs.Add(line1);

    BOM line2 = new BOM();
    line2.Assembly = bike;
    line2.Component = wheel;
    line2.Qty = 2;
    db.BOMs.Add(line2);

    db.SaveChanges();

    return "BOM has been created!";
}

public string ReadBOM()
{
    Item bike = db.Items.Find(3);
    // The following line always returns 0
    return "Components: " + bike.Components.Count.ToString();
}
```

The CreateBOM method works absolutely fine and creates the correct records but the ReadBOM always gives a count = 0! :(

Comment: Did you see the Boom rows in your DB after SaveChanges?

Comment: If I am not wrong, I see you create only two records but trying to read fourth record with: `db.Items.Find(3);` ? Would this be a problem?

Comment: @octavioccl
Yes BOM has the following rows:
AssemblyID    ComponentID     Qty
3                     4                         1
3                     6                         2

Comment: @SivaGopal 3 is the ID of the Assembly in the Items table. I am definitely getting the right item because in ReadBOM bike.Desc == "Bike"

Comment: That's odd, if you haven't disabled lazy loading, `Components` collection should be loaded at the time it's accessed. Debug your code and take a look the result type of `Find` method and check is a big name.

Comment: @Caltor Are you trying to find Item with Id '3' or Assembly/BOM with Id '3'? If you need to find Assembly/BOM then you need to change the query?

Comment: what version of EF are you using?

Comment: Just to do a test, try `Item bike = db.Items.Include(i=>i.Components).FirstOrDefault(i=>i.ItemID ==3);`

Comment: @octavioccl EF 6.0.0.0
The Find works correctly and gets me the Item that is the top-level of the hierarchy. `return bike.Desc` gives "Bike" so I know it is the right item.
`Item bike = db.Items.Include(i=>i.Components).FirstOrDefault(i=>i.ItemID ==3);` won't compile. I get "Error 1 Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type"

Comment: Are you sure you don't initialize the collections (with new List<BOM> for instance) in the class constructor?

Comment: Yes, because you're missing the namespace `System.Data.Entity`

Comment: Hi @IvanStoev, I also thought about what you suggested, but I discarded that idea due to it would throw an exception instead return 0

Comment: Oh, but bike is not related as a Component, search wich is the id of `Wheel` in your database and try your example with that ID

Comment: @octavioccl haha it compiles now but I still get Components: 0
However interestingly this works:
            `var components = from comp in db.BOMs
                             where comp.AssemblyID == 3
                             select comp;

            return "Components: " + components.Count().ToString();`
but it would be nice to get the navigation properties working if I could.
Correct, bike isn't a component and what I actually want to query is what components belong to a given assembly.

Comment: @octavioccl Hi, my point was that if OP does what I said, it will block the lazy loading.

Comment: Blocking it? Why?. Anyways I think the issue is not related with EF or Linq, it's that bike was not related as `Component`, take a look his example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code is working well, the issue is you are getting from your DB an `Item` (`Bike`) that was not related as a `Component` when you create `BOOM` entity instance.

If you try:

```
return "Assemblies: " + bike.Assemblies.Count.ToString();
```

You will get the expected result, because bike was just related as `Assembly`

Comment: That's it! The Assemblies and Components navigation properties are the wrong way round! How do I fix that please?

Comment: Setting `Component` navigation property with bike at the time you create a BOOM instance

Comment: That doesn't make sense though. Bike is not a component of Wheel. Wheel is a component of Bike. Bike is an Assembly of Wheel and Frame. Can I fix it with Fluent API?

Comment: I don't think this is a problem you can solve with fluent api, is something that is part of your logic, If you save in some point a bike as a `Component` then when you access to `Components` navigation properties you will get the related BOOM entities

Comment: but in CreateBOM I have `line1.Assembly = bike;` and not `line1.Component = bike;`. I really don't understand why it thinks bike is a component when I am clearly saying it is an assembly and that wheel and frame are components but EF thinks they are assemblies!

Comment: But where is that you see that EF is treating bike as a `Component` or wheel as `Assembly`. If you take a look the id of wheel in your DB an execute this, you will see is working well: `Item wheel= db.Items.Find(wheelId);wheel.Components.Count.ToString();`

Comment: I've sorted it! I had the foreign keys the wrong way around in Fluent API. Can I edit your answer with the correction please?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
line1.AssemblyID = bike.ItemID;
line1.ComponentID = frame.ItemID;
```

If your `ItemID` is auto generate by DB, you can `SaveChanges()` before create `BOM`.

Comment: Is that instead of or as well as:
    line1.Assembly = bike;            line1.Component = frame;

Comment: Same result: Count = 0
The creation of the BOM is NOT a problem. It's the reading of it back that is the problem. For some reason EF isn't populating the ICollection navigation properties. I think it might be because I have two relationships between the tables and EF doesn't know what to do but unfortunately that is the correct design for a Bill Of Materials.